# Как предотвратить повторную отправку формы?

Tags: php, post, form

есть форма поиска через POST.Выводятся результаты поиска,кликаешь на товар,а при возвращении к результатам браузер просит повторную отправку.

форма:

```
<form method="post" class="searchNav text-center" action="/search">
     <input type="text" href="/search" name="search" placeholder="search" >
     <button  class="fa fa-search"></button>

</form>
```

обработчик:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])){

            if (!empty($_POST['search'])) {
                $searchResult = $_POST['search'];
                $searchResult = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchResult);
                $searchResult=htmlspecialchars($searchResult);
                $sResult = Product::searchResult($searchResult);

            }

        };
```

Comment: Сделайте поиск GET запросом

Comment: Для таких случаев и существует GET запросы
ИМХО... За такое бить по рукам и ногам надо....
Вот представь, надо тебе другу скинуть этот список товаров, это не сможешь сделать, еще вымораживает при сравнении нескольких товаров в интернет магазинах электроники это в сессии и куки пихают, и нет функции генерации ссылки на это сравнение
P. S. накипело

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запросы **GET** — это **получение** информации, которое не меняет её состояние.

Запросы **POST** — это **отправка** информации, которая потенциально может изменить состояние.

Если следовать этому правилу, то решается множество проблем: как изменение данных случайными повторными запросами в случае GET вместо POST, так и невозможность поделиться ссылкой в случае POST вместо GET.

Поиск — это исключительно получение информации. Почти всегда это должен быть запрос GET. Кроме прочего, это решит вашу проблему с защитой браузера от повторной отправки запроса POST.

Answer (score 0):

Используй **GET-запросы** для подобных операций, т.к. они позволяют однозначно декодировать основной смысл поиска(прочитать про GET-запросы можно [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php))
И вообще, на будущее, используй **POST-запросы** - только для передачи секретной информации, которая не должна "быть известна всем", в другом же случае - get-запросы.

Comment: "Секретность" слабо соотносится с выбором между GET и POST. Секретны обычно логин, пароль и сессия, но логин и пароль должны отправляться через POST как изменяющие состояние, а сессия может передаваться как печенье.

Comment: Я имел ввиду конкретно для передачи данных и данных которые должны/не должны быть известны всем(что называется "на пальцах объяснил")